# ErrorException: Undefined index: data in ../app/Widgets/TopMenu.php:23

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5

Update: Issue Resolved.

I'm getting this error stating undefined index 'data' at line 26, I've tried to use isset on top but nothing to avail. Any help highly appreciated.

```
    class TopMenu extends AbstractWidget {
    /**
     * Treat this method as a controller action.
     * Return view() or other content to display.
     */
    public function run()
    {

       $SDKInstance = new BlackLabelSdk();
       $listFilter = $SDKInstance->getFilterList();
       
    return view("widgets.top_menu", [
            'categories' => Categorymodel::archives(),
            'blacklabelFilter' => $listFilter['data']['categories']
    ]);
    
    }
}
```

Edits:

This is my BlackLabelSdk()

```
   /**
 * Get the entire filter list for sorting performers.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getFilterList()
{
  return $this->requestProcessor('filters', 'GET');
}
```

And this is my view

```
<body>
<?php echo app('arrilot.widget')->run('TopMenu'); ?>
```

Comment: what is the value of your `$listFilter` ? can you use `dd()` on it, please?

Comment: Because I think this error is specifically because you're accessing the `data` index of `$listFilter` which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: This is what I got when dd($listFilter);

array:2 [▼
  "errors" => array:1 [▶]
  "sessionId" => "max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0"
]

Comment: what's `$SDKInstance->getFilterList();` do?

Comment: Obviously the error lies here $listFilter['data'] so why the isset() didn't helped? How did you use it?

try dumping out what you have in the filter using dd($listFilter) and you will see if you have 'data' item in the array, as long as the variable also is an array.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure that before you return the view() you have the data available.**

```
$listFilter = $SDKInstance->getFilterList();

$result = null;
if (isset($listFilter['errors'])){
     // do something with the errors
   $result = // store the errors and present them in the view or something
} 
else
{
    // all good so here you should have `$listFilter['data']` available.
   $result = $listFilter['data']['categories'];
}
       
return view("widgets.top_menu", [
       'categories' => Categorymodel::archives(),
       'blacklabelFilter' => $result
]);
```